# Excluding part of mesh from rigid body simulation?

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigid-body-simulation

For instance, if I was simulating a cartoony bomb, the type with the long fuse, how could I exclude the fuse from the rest of the mesh in the rigid body simulator? The only workaround I can think of would be to separate it and then parent it to the rest of the bomb. Is what I've described possible?

Comment: If the bomb is going to move, I would make the fuse a soft body simulation and parent it to the bomb.

Comment: Thanks. I tested the workaround and it should work fine. I'll just leave this up in case it gets answered.